# C: Why I am getting a Segmentation Fault when trying to create a new folder/directory?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, mkdir, stat, opendir

I am trying to create a new folder using two command line arguments, one being the destination folder and the other the source, but I am getting a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error.  Could you please help me figure out what is causing this error. The code is below.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char *src = argv[1];
    char *dest = argv[2];

    DIR *srcdir;
    DIR *destdir;

    struct stat srcfile;
    struct stat destfile;
    struct dirent* directory;


    if ((stat(argv[1], &srcfile) == -1) || (stat(argv[2], &src) == -1)){
        exit(-1); //TODO: Change to proper error code
    }

    srcdir = opendir(src);
    destdir = opendir(dest);

    if ((srcdir == NULL)||(destdir == NULL)) {
        printf("No such file or directory exist.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char new_path[1024];

    new_path[0] = '\0';
    strcat(new_path, dest);
    strcat(new_path, "/");

    strcat(new_path, src); 

    if (stat(new_path, &destfile) == -1) {
        if(mkdir(new_path, 0700) != -1){
            mkdir(new_path, 0700);
        }else{
            perror("mkdir: ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to use this: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Opening-a-Directory.html

Comment: What are the values of src and dest?

Comment: @jay: I am just writing the name of two folders that are in the same directory as the function.

Comment: This code fragment (in line 14?) is wrong: `(stat(argv[2], &src)`, and may be there are other errors. The answer below looks correct, but you should in first place look at warnings from compiler.

Comment: You call `stat` with `struct stat *` in one case and `char **` in another case... they can't both be right. Check manual for stat.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and the following code is working correctly as:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    char *src = argv[1];
    char *dest = argv[2];

    DIR *srcdir;
    DIR *destdir;

    struct stat srcfile;
    struct stat destfile;
    //struct dirent* directory;


    if ((stat(src, &srcfile) == -1) || (stat(dest, &destfile) == -1)){
        exit(0); //TODO: Change to proper error code
    }

    srcdir = opendir(src);
    destdir = opendir(dest);

    if ((srcdir == NULL)||(destdir == NULL)) {
        printf("No such file or directory exist.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char new_path[1024];

    new_path[0] = '\0';
    strcat(new_path, dest);
    strcat(new_path, "/");

    strcat(new_path, src); 

    if (stat(new_path, &destfile) == -1) {
        if(mkdir(new_path, 0700) != -1){
            mkdir(new_path, 0700);
        }else{
            perror("mkdir: ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiling command

```
gcc -Wall xxx.c
```

Comment: Nice work, but probably an explanation about the changes you made to the code would be better.